# if string contains substring twig

Tags: theming, 8

I feel a bit dummy as I can't make it work..

I'm trying to check if a string contains substring in my twig.

```
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{{ url }}

{% if 'my-delivery' in url %}
    //print something
{% endif %}
```

The url is printed outside the if statement but it doesn't enter the if statement and the url contains 'my-delivery'.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why not do this in a preprocess hook? Would be easier.

Comment: You have a point! At some point I sent the url from the preprocess_page but I didn't think to send just the result... Thank you so much! On the other hand I feel a bit embarrassed not being able to write an if in twig!!!

Comment: IMO conditional output in twig based on URL could be hairy. I can imagine that caching can get in the way of what someone should be seeing.

Comment: You have one more point! But at this point I don't know if there is any other option to handle what I wanna do. I'm working with field collection items. I load the node edit form in a page using panels and custom block. By default Drupal wraps the field collection item in a table which I want to avoid. So I was thinking to alter the template based on my current page only.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The twig function `url()` returns a render array, when you render it with the twig filter `|render` you get a markup object and when you render it again you get a string, which you can check whether it contains a substring:

```
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{% if 'test' in url|render|render %}
  <p>url contains "test"</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: ```render_var()``` is great way to get an array to string https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3ArenderVar/8.2.x

Answer (score 3):

`url()` returns an array, as 4x4 says. You can see this if you do a for loop on the variable.

`path()`, however, seems to return a string that you can do your operation on. But it won't include hostname.

Comment: it gives the path alias. what about the base url? for example, I want 'taxonomy/term/1' not the word 'students' which I used as alias