# How do I get the current path and add a condition in page.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I have the view page called "location/all" which contain all the map details.

I changed some CSS styles.

```
<!--<div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">!-->
{% if 'location/all' in url %}
  <div role="main" class="main-container js-quickedit-main-content">
{% else %}
 <div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
{% endif %}
```

I tried this code to check the condition, but every time it executes the `else` part.

Comment: in which twig file are you writing this code

Comment: themes\custom\themesname(XXXXX)\templates\system
inside page.html.twig

Comment: is it a suggestion for view-view.html.twig file

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239105/if-string-contains-substring-twig

Comment: Got the answer
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{% if 'location/all' in url|render|render %}
 <div role="main" class="main-container js-quickedit-main-content">
{% else %}
 <div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
{% endif %}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GOt the Answer

```
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{% if 'location/all' in url|render|render %}
<div role="main" class="main-container js-quickedit-main-content">
{% else %}
<div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
{% endif %}
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: it gives the path alias. what about the base url? for example I want 'taxonomy/term/1' not the word 'students' which I used as alias.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
{% if 'location/all' in url('<current>')|render|render %}
```

**Alternative solution** would be to add the following to your `THEMENAME.theme`

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['path'] = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
}
```

and use this in your `page.html.twig`

```
{% if 'location/all' in path %}
```

Comment: wouldn't [`path('<current>')`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path) be better to use? it gets the path instead of the entire URL. either way it's an alternative to `url`

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code.

```
<!--<div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">!-->
{% if '/location/all' == url('<current>') %}
  <div role="main" class="main-container js-quickedit-main-content">
{% else %}
 <div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: HI jeetendra,
thanks for comment its not reflecting

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code

{% set current_url = url('') %}
{% if 'location/all' in current_url|render|render %}

{% else %}

{% endif %}