# How do I stringify objects or at least get a string value?

Tags: 8, theming

The `item.content` for my field item is 'active'. However, when I use a comparison operator as seen below, it never equates to True but always False. I thought maybe some spacing issues was the reason, but that seems to not be the case.

Is the content in `item.content` not a string? I am assuming when I call item.content, its probably a object, but I can't find any documentation on how to turn a object's value into a string so it equates to true.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item.content == 'active' %}
    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item', 'status_item_active') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% else %}
    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item', 'status_item_notactive') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This field should be a boolean I think when the field has two possible values. If you want to get it working as a text field then try to render before comparing, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239105/if-string-contains-substring-twig

Answer (score 4):

You can try this instead

```
{% if element['#items'][key].value == 'active' %}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, comparing the database value from the field item instead of the rendered output. You need to get the key, for example by extending the loop definition: `{% for key, item in items %}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
{% if 'active' in item.content|render|render %}
```

Comment: This is risky and unreliable condition, IMO. When you just want to read a value, you shouldn't have to render it out one or more times. See this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/281520/57